# Postgres create view with column values based on another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm implementing a view to store leaderboard data of the **top 10 users** that is computed using an expensive `COUNT(*)`. I'm planning on the view to look something like this:

```sql
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
user_id TEXT
type TEXT
rank INTEGER
count INTEGER

-- adding an index to user_id
-- adding a two-column unique index to user_id and type
```

I'm having trouble with seeing how this view should be created to properly account for the `rank` and `type`. Essentially, I have a big table (~30 million rows) like this:

```
+----+---------+---------+----------------------------+
| id | user_id |  type   |         created_at         |
+----+---------+---------+----------------------------+
|  1 |       1 | Diamond | 2021-05-11 17:35:18.399517 |
|  2 |       1 | Diamond | 2021-05-12 17:35:17.399517 |
|  3 |       1 | Diamond | 2021-05-12 17:35:18.399517 |
|  4 |       2 | Diamond | 2021-05-13 17:35:18.399517 |
|  5 |       1 | Clay    | 2021-05-14 17:35:18.399517 |
|  6 |       1 | Clay    | 2021-05-15 17:35:18.399517 |
+----+---------+---------+----------------------------+
```

With the table above, I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
+----+---------+---------+------+-------+
| id | user_id |  type   | rank | count |
+----+---------+---------+------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | Diamond |    1 |     3 |
|  2 |       2 | Diamond |    2 |     1 |
|  3 |       1 | Clay    |    1 |     2 |
|  4 |       1 | Weekly  |    1 |     5 | -- 3 diamonds + 2 clay obtained between Mon-Sun
|  5 |       2 | Weekly  |    2 |     1 |
+----+---------+---------+------+-------+
```

By `Weekly` I am counting the time from the last Sunday to the upcoming Sunday.

Is this doable using only SQL, or is some kind of script needed? If doable, how would this be done? It's worth mentioning that there are thousands of different types, so not having to manually specify `type` would be preferred.

If there's anything unclear, please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between `id` and `user_id`?

Comment: ``id`` is essentially just the row number/id that can be used as the primary key.

Comment: The first three rows of the result can be produced with a `GROUP BY user_id, type` combined with a `RANK()` function. Now, to get the last two rows, you'll need to clarify when does the week start and end.

Comment: The week is essentially from a Sunday (i.e. 19th Dec) to Sunday (i.e. 26th Dec).

Comment: @TheImpaler How exactly does the ``RANK()`` function work in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "weekly" rows are produced in a different way compared to the "user" rows (I called them two different "categories"). To get the result you want you can combine two queries using `UNION ALL`.

For example:

```
select 'u' as category, user_id, type,
  rank() over(partition by type order by count(*) desc) as rk,
  count(*) as cnt
from scores
group by user_id, type
union all
select 'w', user_id, 'Weekly',
  rank() over(order by count(*) desc),
  count(*) as cnt
from scores
group by user_id
order by category, type desc, rk
```

Result:

```
 category  user_id  type     rk  cnt 
 --------- -------- -------- --- --- 
 u         1        Diamond  1   3   
 u         2        Diamond  2   1   
 u         1        Clay     1   2   
 w         1        Weekly   1   5   
 w         2        Weekly   2   1
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3zJXzVgbRWYqj7cJbdkuT3/0).

**Note**: For the sake of simplicity I left the filtering by timestamp out of the query. If you really needed to include *only* the rows of the last 7 days (or other period of time), it would be a matter of adding a `WHERE` clause in both subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were talking about, right?

```
WITH scores_plus_weekly AS ((
        SELECT id, user_id, 'Weekly' AS type, created_at
        FROM scores
        WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2021-05-10' AND '2021-05-17'
    )
    UNION (
        SELECT * FROM scores
    ))
SELECT
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CASE "type" WHEN 'Diamond' THEN 0 WHEN 'Clay' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, count(*) DESC) as "id",
    user_id,
    "type",
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY count(*) DESC) as "rank",
    count(*)
FROM scores_plus_weekly
GROUP BY user_id, "type"
ORDER BY "id";
```

I'm sure this is not the only way, but I thought the result wasn't too complex. This query first combines the original database with all scores from this week. For the sake of consistency I picked a date range that matches your entire example set. It then groups by `user_id` and `type` to get the counts for each combination. The `row_numbers` will give you the overall rank and the rank per type. A big part of this query consists of sorting by `type`, so if you're joining another table that contains the order or priority of the types, the `CASE` can probably be simplified.

Then, lastly, this entire query can be caught in a view using the `CREATE VIEW score_ranks AS` , followed by your query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the detailed explanation! Question: is it possible to not have to specify the diamond/clay? There are quite a lot of types, so manually adding them would be hard.

Comment: I simplified the example a bit, but the best approach would be to have another table that holds an integer value like `order`, that ranks your labels in the correct order. E.g. (label, order) VALUES ('Diamond', 1), ('Gold', 2), ... ('Clay', 6), etc. You can then join that table by label name and take its `order` field as input for sorting.

Comment: I see. TheImpaler said something about using the ``RANK()`` function for the ranking, any ideas on how that could be combined with this solution?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what he had in mind, but it's another function that can be used on a window (the `OVER (...)` part). It counts differently; it starts at 1 and sticks to that number and only increments for each new partition. You can get similar results as with `row_number`, or it could be used as 'preparation', useful input for a followup query.

Comment: I see. I'm trying to understand the query: what exactly does the first ``row_number()`` do?

Comment: It counts the rows and numbers them. The window after it tells when it should restart numbering (the partition part) and in which order it should increment (first by type, then by count in descending order). I removed the `PARTITION BY TRUE` part as it's redundant when it contains an `ORDER BY` clause. Partitioning by `TRUE` is a simple way of saying there's only one partition (e.g. don't reset the counter of `row_number`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240344/discussion-between-californium-and-jboot).